# Dynamically creating movieclip instances

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I use the code below to create 3 movie clips.

```
var A:Array = new Array();

for (var i:uint = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        A[i] = new hayvanSec();
        A[i].x = 240+i*160;
        A[i].y=300;
        addChild(A[i]);
}
```

I have 10 image files in the library. I want to show one of these images inside those dynamically created movie clips randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the flash IDE make those image a `MovieClip` and name your clip with something like that `XXX_0`, `XXX_1`,...,`XXX_9`.
Then you can in your function you can get the random reference to your clip with :

```
var myImageName:String="XXX_"+Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
// and then get the movie from the library
var clazz:Class=ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition(myImageName) as Class;
if (clazz !== null) {
  var mc:MovieClip=MovieClip(new clazz());
  (...).addChild(mc);
}
```